# React native Expo app crashes on real device

Tags: react-native, expo

React native expo app crashes on real device with prod build apk. No error on building apk. I can't find what's the issue is. I am using below packages.

```
    "dependencies": {
    "@expo/vector-icons": "^13.0.0",
    "@react-native-async-storage/async-storage": "1.18.2",
    "@react-native-community/masked-view": "^0.1.11",
    "@react-navigation/drawer": "^6.6.3",
    "@react-navigation/material-bottom-tabs": "^6.2.16",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^6.1.7",
    "@react-navigation/stack": "^6.3.17",
    "@reduxjs/toolkit": "^1.9.5",
    "axios": "^1.4.0",
    "expo": "~49.0.8",
    "expo-location": "^16.1.0",
    "expo-permissions": "^14.2.1",
    "expo-status-bar": "~1.6.0",
    "expo-task-manager": "^11.3.0",
    "react": "18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-native": "0.72.4",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "~2.12.0",
    "react-native-maps": "^1.7.1",
    "react-native-paper": "^5.10.3",
    "react-native-reanimated": "~3.3.0",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "4.6.3",
    "react-native-screens": "~3.22.0",
    "react-native-vector-icons": "^10.0.0",
    "react-native-web": "~0.19.6",
    "react-redux": "^8.1.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.20.0",
    "@types/react": "~18.0.14",
    "@types/react-native": "^0.72.2",
    "typescript": "^5.1.3"
  },
```

Comment: what's the crash stack trace? this is impossible to answer without that, and then the code that the stack trace shows (if it's your code).